# Script bash to compress .mp4 with subfolders and another destination folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a script to convert all .mp4 videos into subfolders.
My hierarchy is :

Folder_1/
    Videos_encoded/
    Videos_orig/
            first-video.mp4
            video_2/
                video-in-folder-video_2.mp4

I want to compress all .mp4 (with into subfolders) are in the *Videos-orig/* to the *videos_encoded* as the destination folder.

I tried :

```
find /home/user/Folder_1/videos_orig/ -type d | while read ligne     
do  
cd "$ligne"          
   for i in *.mp4;
    do 
       ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -ar 44100 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000 -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k /home/user/Folder_1/videos_encoded"$(basename "${i/.mp4}").mp4"
    done     
done
```

But I have the error message : **.mp4 no such file or directory* (result of ffmpeg command).

I don't understand ...

There is it a better way to perform this project ?

Thanks you very much in advance for your help :)

Regards

Comment: use -exec flag in find.

Answer (score 0):

If not preserving the directory structure in the output is fine, I think this example would be sufficient by solely using `find` with `-exec`

```
find orig/ -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "{}" "encoded/$(basename {})"' \;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, I modify my script with your command line, and now, the result ffmpeg command is : /video_orig/myvideo/myvideo.mp4 : Is a directory . The video and the directory are same but the .mp4 is not a directory ^^ .

PS : I'm deleted the first $ because " $ : command not found" .

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Hmm, that's odd, I updated the answer with an additional option `-type f` to make sure the argument passed to `ffmpeg` is guaranteed a file instead of directory. By the way that `$` is just there to indicate that the code is a bash command :) I'll remove it to avoid confusion

Comment: Oh thanks you very much ! It's works great with the `-type f` . But, ffmpeg convert many files in same time. Is it possible to convert one by one ?

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Glad to help :) That's quite strange since the `find -exec \;` syntax should execute the command (ffmpeg) in sequence rather than in parallel. would you mind posting your full command?

Comment: Hi thanks,

Finaly, it's ok. The script compress one by one, it's perfect. But I realized that it didn't compress (or detect) the last file in the folder.

I have 5 .mp4 files in the `videos_orig` folder. The script just compressed the first four files. If I have 6 files in my folder, the script will compress first five file without the last .

My command line :
`find /Folder_1/videos_orig/ -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -y -i "{}" -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000 -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k "/Folder_1/videos_encoded/$(basename {})"' \;`

Sorry for my english ^^

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Your command seems good to me, can you try a `find /Folder_1/videos_orig/ -type f -name "*.mp4" -print` to see how many files that `find` actually detected?

Comment: Hi,

Now, I've 13 differents mp4 files in my video_orig but the script compressed only 7 files ... If I try "find /Folder_1/videos_orig/ -type f -name "*.mp4" -print, I have 13 files right. I don't understand ...

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Could it be that some of those mp4 files from the `videos_orig` directory have the same filename, so that some of the encoded files gets overwrited by ffmpeg?

Comment: No, my files are differents names because are video with the date & time "ddmmyyyy_hh-mm-ss.mp4". Also, I have delete `-y`option in my command. It's strange.

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon I'm near clueless now... Another way I can suggest to do is to add a `-report` option to `ffmpeg`, it will generate log files for each file it processes, see if you can find any clue from there

Comment: Hi,

I tried this command line on a Linux but it saves only 7 files in my synology.

It's strange because I have 13 files in the source folder, and in my destination folder, after 7 files, it's replace one by one ... I'm impress there is a limit in my folder on in the command line to create only 7 different files. I tried an other way but I don't understand.

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Just curious, would the same thing happen if you replace `ffmpeg` with `cp`, for example `find orig/ -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c 'cp -v "{}" "encoded/$(basename {})"' \;`

Comment: With this command, I have the same number in the destination folder. The command copied my 13 files in the dest folder. The problem will is in my ffmpeg command so ?

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Great! At least we can know that it is not a hardware or a `find` problem, I suspect that some of the videos (those that weren't copied) cannot be encoded properly, maybe you can try a manual `ffmpeg` command on one of those videos and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: I encoded my videos one by one, with the same ffmpeg command and I have 5-6 videos with an error " moov atom not found " .
It is possible that these errors are problems ?

Comment: @AurélienPéruchon Yup, I think that's the issue, you might want to look into other resources to help you recover those damaged mp4 files such as [here](http://muzso.hu/2012/11/14/how-to-fix-a-broken-mp4-mov-video-ffmpeg-reports-moov-atom-not-found).

Answer (score 0):

The command works, but it doesn't compress all of my files.

My command line :

`find /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/ -type f -name "*.mp*" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -n -i "{}" -crf 23 -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000 -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k "/volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/Cours_videos/$(basename {})"' \;`

I run :
`find /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/ -type f -name "*.mp4" -print`

and I have :

> Sortie standard/erreur :
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-13_131756.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-23_132120.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-24_090340.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-24_131336.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-25_085744.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-25_131357.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-26_133340.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-27_083836.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-27_133906.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-13_090642.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-10_125731.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-10_090037.mp4
>
> /volume1/Master_1/Unites_communes/No_compressed/2017-10-04_140230.mp4
>
> Total : 13 Files

In the destination I have only 7 files compressed and that it.

I have a problem in my ffmpeg command ?

I'm on a Synology, if it can help you.